# Dynamic dropdown list option is not populating afer adding multiple column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add table item dynamically .Now i have problem that when  i select new dynamically created select item from drop-down its corresponding drop-down list does not get its value.And i get  "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of null".I think the problem is with the parameter passing to the function which is called if select is change but cannot find any way to resolve it .I am adding code snippet

```
 <table class="tg" style="undefined;table-layout: fixed; width: 657px"  id="customFields" >
<colgroup>
<col style="width: 222px">
<col style="width: 216px">
<col style="width: 219px">
<col style="width: 219px">
<col style="width: 219px">
<col style="width: 219px">
<col style="width: 219px">
<col style="width: 219px">
</colgroup>
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-hgcj" rowspan="2"><br>Honours</th>
    <th class="tg-hgcj" colspan="2">General</th>
    <th class="tg-hgcj" colspan="2">Bank Transaction Details</th>
    <th class="tg-hgcj"rowspan="2" >See MP</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-093g">Sub1</td>
    <td class="tg-093g">Sub2</td>
    <td class="tg-093g">Bank Transaction id</td>
    <td class="tg-093g">Bank Transaction date</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-30rh"><select name="hons[]" id="ddl" onchange="configureDropDownLists(this,document.getElementById('ddl2'));disable_select();">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="Physics">Physics</option>
<option value="Chemistry">Cemistry</option>
<option value="Math">Math</option>
</select>

<select id="ddl2" name="session[]">
</select>
</td>
    <td class="tg-30rh"><input type="text" name="sub1[]"placeholder="Subject1"class="text-uppercase"></td>
    <td class="tg-30rh"><input type="text" name="sub2[]"placeholder="Subject2"class="text-uppercase"></td>
    <td class ="tg-30rh"><input type="text" name="tran_id[]"></td>
    <td class ="tg-30rh"><input type="text" name="tran_date[]"></td>
    <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="addCF">Add</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And the scripts

```
$(document).ready(function(){var x=0;var y ='ddl';var z='ddl2';
    $(".addCF").click(function(){
        $("#customFields").append('<tr><td class="tg-30rh"><select name="hons[]" id='+y+x+' onchange="configureDropDownLists(this,document.getElementById('+z+x+'));disable_select();"><option value=""></option><option value="Physics">Physics</option><option value="Chemistry">Cemistry</option><option value="Math">Math</option></select><select id='+z+x+' name="session"></select>\
</td>\
    <td class="tg-30rh"><input type="text" name="sub1[]"placeholder="Subject1"class="text-uppercase"></td>\
    <td class="tg-30rh"><input type="text" name="sub2[]"placeholder="Subject2"class="text-uppercase"></td>\
    <td class ="tg-30rh"><input type="text" name="tran_id[]"></td>\
    <td class ="tg-30rh"><input type="text" name="tran_date[]"></td>\
    <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF">Remove</a></td></tr>');x++;
    });
    $("#customFields").on('click','.remCF',function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });
});


function configureDropDownLists(ddl1,ddl2) {
    var physics = new Array('Morning','Day','Night');
    var chemistry = new Array('Day', 'Evening');
    var math = new Array('Morning', 'Day');

    switch (ddl1.value) {
        case 'Physics':
            ddl2.options.length = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < physics.length; i++) {
                createOption(ddl2, physics[i], physics[i]);
            }
            break;
        case 'Chemistry':
            ddl2.options.length = 0; 
        for (i = 0; i < chemistry.length; i++) {
            createOption(ddl2, chemistry[i], physics[i]);
            }
            break;
        case 'Math':
            ddl2.options.length = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < math.length; i++) {
                createOption(ddl2, math[i], math[i]);
            }
            break;
            default:
                ddl2.options.length = 0;
            break;
    }

}

    function createOption(ddl, text, value) {
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.value = value;
        opt.text = text;
        ddl.options.add(opt);
    }
```

How do i add multiple row in table  and populate select list accordingly.

for example :
  if i select Physics in first then second list option should be morning,day ,evening 
this is not happning for dynamically created rows;

Comment: I have just made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/sw3sz9fj/) with your code..here it is working correctly i think..

Comment: what item you try to remove? #customField is related to the table, and you remove an element which is two steps outwards of it?

Comment: @mico all the item in the newly created row .which has remove button

Comment: @Lal no 2nd droup down list is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this part of your dynamically added HTML:

```
onchange="configureDropDownLists(this,document.getElementById('+z+x+'));disable_select();"
```

You need to put quotes into the generated HTML around the computed string expression `z+x`.  Right now it is generating HTML that looks like this:

```
onchange="configureDropDownLists(this,document.getElementById(ddl20));disable_select();"
```

The browser thinks you want to read the value of the variable `ddl20`, which doesn't exist.  Correction:

```
onchange="configureDropDownLists(this,document.getElementById(\''+z+x+'\'));disable_select();"
```